# Page 21 of Enderton's Elements of Set Theory - Subset axioms

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To my understanding the subset axiom is just an axiom that says that given a set and a property, we can have a set defined as all the members of the original set for which the property is true. If I had to put this in symbols it would be something like:
$\forall A \exists B \forall x (x \in B \iff x \in A \land P(x))$

However in Enderton's book the subset axiom is not only one but multiple:

> Subset Axioms: For each formula __ not containing $B$ the following is an axiom:
>
> $\forall t_{1}... \forall t_{k} \forall c \exists B \forall x (x \in B \iff x\in c \land \text{__})$

I guess my question is why is it done in this manner? Why multiple axioms instead of just one? and more importantly, what are those $t_{1}...t{k}$ Enderton is taling about. This whole section has me very confused I would appreciate any help in understanding why the Subset Axioms is formulated the way it is and what are those $t_{1}...t{k}$ supposed to represent? Thanks.

Comment: 1) "Why multiple axioms instead of just one?" Your "one" axiom $\forall A \exists B \forall x (x \in B \iff x \in A \land P(x))$ is also ["multiple" (one for each formula $P(x)$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema). 2) "what are those $t_{1}...t{k}$": other free variables than $x$ in his "formula  __ ". So, his (family of) axiom(s) is more general than yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues. First, the informal notion of "property" is being made precise via the notion of "formula" (in the language of ZF set theory, L(ZF)). We can't quantify over formulas: $\forall \varphi(\ldots)\ldots$ isn't allowed in L(ZF).

Second, the $t_i$'s are called *parameters*. They allow us to parametrize a property.

Let me first give a couple of examples, then some more background.

Suppose we want to form the subset of all elements of $A$ that are unordered pairs. The formula for the property "$x$ is an unordered pair" is
$$\exists y\exists z\forall u(u\in x\Leftrightarrow u=y\vee u=z)$$
so copying this into the Subset Axiom Schema, we have this instance:
$$\forall A\exists B\forall x(x\in B\Leftrightarrow x\in A\wedge\exists y\exists z\forall u(u\in x\Leftrightarrow u=y\vee u=z))$$
As that's a bit of a mess, we might allow abbreviations, at least informally. Say $UP(x)$ abbreviates the first formula I gave; then we write simply
$$\forall A\exists B\forall x(x\in B\Leftrightarrow x\in A\wedge UP(x))$$
to mean the same thing.

Or say for a given set $A$, we want the subset of all ordered pairs $(t,u)\in A$ whose first element is a given set $t$. This is useful in working with relations. There is a formula in L(ZF), which I will abbreviate $OP(x,t,u)$, that means $x=(t,u)$--pardon me for not writing it out. So we have
$$\forall t\forall A\exists B\forall x(x\in B\Leftrightarrow x\in A\wedge \exists u\;OP(x,t,u))$$
This time we have a parameter $t$. Our set $B$ is a subset of $A$, but which subset depends on $t$.

OK, a little background. ZF is an example of a first-order theory in the predicate calculus. The idea is we have a fully formal language, L(ZF), with precise syntax rules, and the whole development can in principle be done in L(ZF). (*Only* in principle, in practice the formulas soon become ridiculously long.) Enderton discusses this briefly on pp. 22-23 and more thoroughly in the appendix.

The Subset Axiom started out as the Axiom of Separation in Zermelo's 1908 paper "Investigations in the foundations of set theory", as follows:

> A question or assertion $\mathfrak{E}$ is said to be “*definite*” if the fundamental
> relations of the domain, by means of the axioms and the universally valid laws
> of logic, determine without arbitrariness whether it holds or not. Likewise a
> “propositional function” $\mathfrak{E}(x)$, in which the variable term $x$ ranges over all
> individuals of a class $\mathfrak{K}$, is said to be “definite” if it is definite for *each single*
> individual $x$ of the class $\mathfrak{K}$. Thus the question whether $a\in b$ or not is always
> definite, as is the question whether $M\subseteq N$ or not.
>
> ....
>
> **Axiom III.** Whenever the propositional function $\mathfrak{E}(x)$ is definite for
> all elements of a set $M$, $M$ possesses a subset $M_\mathfrak{E}$ containing as elements
> precisely those elements $x$ of $M$ for which $\mathfrak{E}(x)$ is true.

Zermelo is the Z of ZF. Zermelo's treatment was axiomatic, but not formal in the sense of mathematical logic (i.e., predicate calculus). Fraenkel (the F of ZF) then suggested that Zermelo's somewhat vague notion of a "definite" property should be replaced with the precise notion of a formula of the predicate calculus, for a language with a single relation symbol "$\in$"--what we now call L(ZF).

In predicate calculus we have the quantifiers $\exists$ and $\forall$, which are *part of the language* L(ZF). When we say "there exists a formula $\varphi$" or "for all formulas $\varphi$", these quantifiers are *metamathematical* and not part of L(ZF). So as I said, we are not allowed to write $\forall \varphi\ldots$ in L(ZF). Instead, to express the Subset Axiom as Zermelo envisaged it, we need an axiom schema, with one axiom for every formula $\varphi$.

The Subset Axiom schema would not be strong enough without parameters. Often the subset you want to extract depends on parameters. E.g., once you've proven the existence of the product $X\times Y$, you might want the subset of all pairs with first element $a\in X$. Or say $R$ is an ordering relation on $X$. We might want the interval $[a,b]=\{u\in X: aRu\wedge uRb\}$. This is a subset of $X$ that depends on the parameters $R$, $a$, and $b$.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. First we cannot quantify over formulas thus why we need an  axiom for every formula, and second, formulas can be predicates that are n-ary, thus we need the parameters there. But why have something  like: $\forall t_{1} ...\forall t_{k} \forall A \exists B \forall x (x \in B \iff x \in A \land P(x, t_{1}, ..., t_{k}))$ instead of having the predicate and its quantifiers all together like this:  $\forall A \exists B \forall x (x \in B \iff x \in A \land \forall t_{1} ...\forall t_{k}P(x, t_{1}, ..., t_{k}))$ Is this just an stylistic  choice?

Comment: I still find this $\forall t$ business confusing. In the example you gave, we can let $\varphi(p,x)=\exists y(OP(p,x,y))$. Presumably we can’t use this in the axiom because it has two free variables rather than one? That is, the rule is that $\varphi$ must have one free variable, and this must be, in our example, $p$.???

Comment: I accidentally left out the $\forall x$ quantifier in my examples. Sorry! Now fixed. I also, unfortunately, was stylistically inconsistent in my choice of variables, which probably made things harder to follow. Also fixed. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: @zlaaemi Moving the $\forall\bar{t}$ quantifiers inside would change the meaning drastically. The original form says that, no matter what value the parameters have, there is a set $B$ of all $x\in A$ satisfying the formula *with that choice of parameters*. The second form demands that *each* $x$ has to satisfy the condition for *every* choice of parameters. Usually this is impossible to do, and you will end up with the empty set.

Comment: @Porky Formulas with several free variables are perfectly ok to use in the axiom. So the formula $\varphi(p,y)$ you give is fine. With the edits I made for stylistic consistency, it would be $\varphi(x,t)\equiv \exists u OP(x,t,u)$. We are selecting $x$'s from the set $A$; the variable $u$ is "quantified out" and not free in $\varphi$; the particular set of $x$'s we end up with depends on the parameter $t$.